# RuntimeError: shape '[784]' is invalid for input of size 7840

Tags: python

Below is the code:

```
import torch

import torchvision

from torchvision import transforms, datasets
```

#Establishing the batch size

```
Batch_size = 10
```

#Downloading the train data

```
train_mnist = datasets.MNIST(root="./data", train=True, download=True,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
```

#Passing the train data into a Dataloader

```
train_set = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_mnist, batch_size=Batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

#Downloading the test data

```
test_mnist = datasets.MNIST(root="./data", train=True, download=True,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
```

#Passing the test data into a Dataloader

```
test_set = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_mnist, batch_size=Batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

#Building the network

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as f
class Netwk(nn.Module):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28*28, 64)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
    self.fc4 = nn.Linear(64, 10)

def Fpropagation(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
    x = self.fc4(x)

return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

return x

net = Netwk()

print(net)
```

#Creating optimization for the loss

```
import torch.optim as optim

Optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)

EPOCHS = 3
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for data in train_set:
        X, y = data
        net.zero_grad()
        output = net(X.view(28*28))
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(loss)
```

#The error i get

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-58-b92f3c4f7059> in <module>()
     10     X, y = data
     11     net.zero_grad()
---> 12     output = net(X.view(28*28))
     13     loss = F.nll_loss(output, y)
     14     loss.backward()

RuntimeError: shape '[784]' is invalid for input of size 7840
```

Have tried to get around it, i seem not able to understand whats wrong. From what have tried googling seems my dimensions have an issue and i dont know how to get the right dimensions If at all its the issue.

Comment: chnage `X.view(28*28)` to `X.view(280*280)`

Comment: @sahasrara62, yes have done that, still get an error.                                                       RuntimeError   Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-39-e40a9c57af4b> in <module>()
     10     X, y = data
     11     net.zero_grad()
---> 12     output = net(X.view(280*280))
     13     loss = F.nll_loss(output, y)
     14     loss.backward()

RuntimeError: shape '[78400]' is invalid for input of size 7840

Comment: @sahasrara62 look at the code here, https://github.com/Elijah-A-W/ALGORITHMS/blob/master/MnestPytorch.ipynb ,thanks.

Comment: i am not in ML area, but it looks like there is a mismatch of the data points and the matrix calculation, you need to see in that area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting about "***Batch***" here. See, **when you're** in the `for loop` and **destructuring your `data`** with the line `X, y = data`. Here, what **you may've thought is `X` is an image** from trainset, but **actually `X` is a batch of images** (10 specifically, as you've set 10 as your `batch_size`) and **`y` similarly is a batch of labels**. Means, your `X` has a shape of something like `10x28x28x1`. Now, you may realize **the line `net(X.view(28*28))`** is actually **squashing your whole batch of 10 images** into a single 28x28=>784 size vector, which is wrong, right? So rather what you might want to do here is something like `net(X.view(-1, 28*28))`, now `-1` will ensure that whatever your batch size is, it remains intact as you're sending data into the model, so now you could easily deduce the shape of X would be `10x784` which is what you want.

Another thing I've noticed, a typo maybe, **your `test_set` and `train_set` are actually the same**. To download the proper test_set, **make sure to send `train=False`** as the parameter.

Comment: I managed to make the correction of Downloading the test_set and set train=False, your explanations helps me really understand how the dimensions work but i still get an error kindly look at it, https://github.com/Elijah-A-W/ALGORITHMS/blob/master/MnestPytorch.ipynb

Comment: Change `Fpropagation()` method name in your model's class (`Netwk()`) to `forward()`, as you're using PyTorch, so you need to make the name of these methods as they've done inside their own implementation, the error should go away then. Another suggestion, in your training loop change `net.zero_grad()` to `Optimizer.zero_grad()`.

Comment: , Thanks alot. It finally worked, am new to deep learning. I get these  challenges alot. Kindly asking are there resources where i can refer and learn properly be able understand what am doing more so with pytorch and deep learning

Comment: Great! to learn about PyTorch, you may go through their tutorial [section](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/) where they show how to build all sorts of models, and for the theoretical part of deep learning you can go through Andrew Ng's youtube videos, it'll give you the basic intuition.